# How are pacemakers selected in athletics events?

Tags: running, athletics

In some athletics running programs, there are pacemakers who set the pace for the opening stages of the race, and then drop out after having set the pace they were asked for. What are the rules on the use of pacemakers and who chooses them?

I've seen anywhere from 1 to 3 pacemakers in middle distance runs. So who chooses how many pacemakers there are? Do all runners submit a time they'd like to be set as the pace and the fastest times are picked? When are multiple pacemakers used, only when the distance is long enough that multiple stages of pacemaking is needed?

Are pacemakers runners of lower distance in that meet who pacemake for money? Or there's a group of dedicated pacemakers?

Comment: For the last part, see [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10335/why-are-pace-setters-allowed-to-go-ahead-with-the-race). Would you consider editing this bit out as I feel it's really a separate question?

Comment: Good point, removed that last part